# How to parametrize binding in wpf UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a wpf Window (`MyWindow`) with its `DataContext` set to the `MyViewModel` view model class:

#### MyWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

      <MyUserControl Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Window>
```

#### MyWindow.xaml.cs

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    MyWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

#### MyViewModel.cs

```
// MyViewModel implements IPropertyChanged
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MyText { get { ... } set { ... } }

    ...
}
```

I would like to pass the binding of the `MyText` property from `MyWindow` to the following UserControl (`MyUserControl`):

#### MyUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            Name="MainTextBox"
            Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  
        />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

#### MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(TextPropertyChangedHandler)
        );

        public static void TextPropertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var MyUserControl = sender as MyUserControl;

            MyUserControl.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I would like to get the content typed in the `Textbox` under `MyUserControl` into `MyViewModel.MyText`. **How can this be achieved?**

I tried to bind `MyText` to the `Text` property in `MyUserControl` and then subsequently binding `Text` in `TextBox` to `Text` from `MyUserControl` but this does not work.

Comment: `MyUserControl` will inherit the `MyWindow`'s `DataContext`, so you actually don't need your custom `Text` dependency property. Do you want to reuse your user control, or is it meant to be used only with this single window?

Comment: @dymanoid it is actually meant to be reused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to bind to the property in the view model from the UserControl programatically.

The `MyUserControl` is used as follows:

```
<UserControls:MyUserControl TargetPropertyName="TestId"/>
```

I just pass the name of the property of the View Model that I wish to bind to inside the user control.

Then inside the user control I make sure to programatically bind the property by name on the `MainTextBox` (here in the `BindTextPropertyToTargetPropertyNameOnce`):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPropertyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TargetPropertyName",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(TargetPropertyNamePropertyChangedHandler)
        );

        public static void TargetPropertyNamePropertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var MyUserControl = sender as MyUserControl;

            MyUserControl.TargetPropertyName = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public string TargetPropertyName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TargetPropertyNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TargetPropertyNameProperty, value);
                BindTextPropertyToTargetPropertyNameOnce()
            }
        }

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool _firstRun = true;

        private void BindTextPropertyToTargetPropertyNameOnce()
        {
            if (_firstRun)
            {
                _firstRun = false;
                var binding = new Binding(TargetPropertyName)
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors = true,
                    NotifyOnValidationError = true
                };

                MainTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            }
        }
    }
```

But still I consider this to be a workaround, there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of `TextPropertyChangedHandler`.

DP needs only `BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag, without callback

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
);
```

`TextBox.Text` should bind to `MyUserControl.Text`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyUserControl" x:Name="self"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=self}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

validation properties should go to binding in Window:

```
<MyUserControl Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```